# Can You Build a Next.js Server While That Server is Running?

Tags: next.js

This seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find an answer in the Next documentation.  If I have started a Next.js server:

```
$ npm run start
```

and I get an update to the site:

```
$ git pull
```

can I re-build the server:

```
$ npm run build
```

*while it's still running* ... or will that crash the server?

If it will crash it, is the a best practice to build everything to a separate directory, and then copy it over to deploy?

Comment: semi-helpful: typically "start" would read files into memory and not "watch" the files, so "build" would not affect the running process. But i havent tested this, just a thought

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same thought, every time I update my code and build it for production, I am stopping my server and restarting it.

To experiment, I tried:
npm run build.
npm run start.
Then, made a change to the code.
I kept the server running.
and in a different terminal window,I did npm run build.
But, unfortunately, it crashed the app.
So, I had to stop the server and ran `npm run start` again in the original terminal window.

Unless it is a completely static site or in dev mode, I think stopping and restarting the server is necessary.